# How to force Stripe subscription.trial_will_end event to trigger 7 days before instead of 3 days

Tags: stripe-payments

From 18th of April, the [guidelines](https://support.stripe.com/questions/2020-visa-trial-subscription-requirement-changes-guide) around Visa trial subscriptions are changing. One of these changes requires site owners who give free trials, to send a notifications to their customers about trial end 7 days before.

Currently Stripe's `subscription.trial_will_end` event, [triggers 3 days before trial end](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials).

Is there a way to change this value to 7 to be inline with the guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround for this. According to the last paragraph in [this page](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials), the event [invoice.upcoming](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.upcoming), can be used to achieve the same result.